# How to use the Digitus Serial to USB Adapter?

Tags: usb, adapter, serial-port

How do I connect to the Serial port with the Digitus Serial to USB Adapter?

Comment: You can also use other programs... I changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Connect your Serial cable to the adapter.
- Connect the adapter to your USB port.
- Enter `dmesg | tail` into the terminal.
- There should be a line like:

  > [49172.288653] usb 1-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
- Open Putty with `gksudo putty` in the terminal.
- Select `Serial` and enter `/dev/ttyUSB0` (or similar what you got two steps before)

Comment: Also don't forget, that your user should be member of the group 'dialout'